# Not able to load the Gridview on Load

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am not able to load the gridview on page load. It keeps giving me

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.
I have mnetioned the code and the handler beneath. Please help me solve the issue. The issue happens in the Jquery.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function () {
                 BindGridView();

             });


 function BindGridView() {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "../Pm/uc/G.ashx/GetMailDetail",
                 contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                 data: {},
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (data) {
                     if (data.d.length > 0) {
                         $("#grdDemo").append("<tr><th>Username</th></tr>");
                         for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

                             $("#grdDemo").append("<tr><td>" + 
                             data.d[i].Username + "</td> <td>");
                         }
                     }
                 },
                 error: function (result) {
                 }
             });
         }
        </script>

     <asp:GridView ID="grdDemo" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
```

This is in the Handler.( You can replace the query with anything.)

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //int mailid = int.Parse(context.Request["mid"]);
        //var detail = GetMailDetail(mailid);
        var detail = GetMailDetail();

        if (detail != null)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            string json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(detail);
            context.Response.Write(json);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        }
    }

    //protected object GetMailDetail(int mailid)
    protected object GetMailDetail()
    {
        List<DetailsClass> Detail = new List<DetailsClass>();

        Connection Con = new Connection();
        String Connection = Con.Active_Connection();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connection);
        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Sp4_Txt from  Sp4", con);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dtGetData = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(dtGetData);

        foreach (DataRow dtRow in dtGetData.Rows)
        {
            DetailsClass DataObj = new DetailsClass();
            DataObj.Username = dtRow["Sp4_Txt"].ToString();
            Detail.Add(DataObj);
        }

        return Detail.ToArray();
    }
    public class DetailsClass //Class for binding data
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi can you declared the function "function BindGridView()" before the $(document).ready  any change?

Comment: Why are you accessing `data.d.length`? Where is the `d`? What do you expect that to be? Did you look in the browser's network console to make sure you receive what you expect from the server in your AJAX call?

Comment: Why aren't you handling your [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) objects like SqlConnection properly? Why are you first getting the data into a DataTable rather than just going directly to your strongly typed class?

Comment: Can someone please help me with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

This error is coming because you are accessing the `data.d` without checking `data` and accessing `data.d.length` without checking `data.d`

Do something like this:

```
if(data){
    if(data.d){
        if (data.d.length > 0) {
                 $("#grdDemo").append("<tr><th>Username</th></tr>");
                 for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

                     $("#grdDemo").append("<tr><td>" + 
                     data.d[i].Username + "</td> <td>");
                 }
             }
      }
}
```